# Find all hrefs in page and replace with link maintaining previous link - PHP

Tags: php, hyperlink, text-processing

I'm trying to find all href links on a webpage and replace the link with my own proxy link.

For example

```
<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Needs to be

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/?loadpage=http://www.google.com">Google</a>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use PHP's `DomDocument` to parse the page

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();

// load the string into the DOM (this is your page's HTML), see below for more info
$doc->loadHTML('<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>');

//Loop through each <a> tag in the dom and change the href property
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('a') as $anchor) {
    $link = $anchor->getAttribute('href');
    $link = 'http://www.example.com/?loadpage='.urlencode($link);
    $anchor->setAttribute('href', $link);
}
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Check it out here: http://codepad.org/9enqx3Rv

If you don't have the HTML as a string, you may use cUrl ([docs](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)) to grab the HTML, or you can use the `loadHTMLFile` method of `DomDocument`

**Documentation**

- `DomDocument` - http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php
- `DomElement` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php
- `DomElement::getAttribute` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.getattribute.php
- `DOMElement::setAttribute` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/domelement.setattribute.php
- `urlencode` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php
- `DomDocument::loadHTMLFile` - http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php
- cURL - http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php

Comment: Thank you! I ended up having to do this since you can't access the dynamic value of property "src" in an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Just another option if you would like to have the links replaced with by jQuery you could also do the following:

```
$(document).find('a').each(function(key, element){
   curValue = element.attr('href');
   element.attr('href', 'http://www.example.com?loadpage='+curValue);

});
```

However a more secure way is doing it in php offcourse.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way I can think to do this:

```
$loader = "http://www.example.com?loadpage=";
$page_contents = str_ireplace(array('href="', "href='"), array('href="'.$loader, "href='".$loader), $page_contents);
```

But that might have some problems with urls containing ? or &.  Or if the text (not code) of the document contains href="

Comment: This is why you don't use RegEx for HTML, or treat HTML like a string